# How to get single quotation marks of a command treated as normal quotation marks on (bash) shell script? （trouble with dcm2niix）

Tags: bash, shell

I was writing a bash script for using Dcm2niix. Dcm2niix's command includes single quotation marks. I tried to add single quotation marks on the script in many ways but it doesn't work.

My working system (environment?) is: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.
Dcm2niix is a DICOM to NifTI converter. It convert `.dcm` files to `.nii` files.
Its command is normally like:

`dcm2niix [options] <sourcedir>`

`<sourcedir>` is like:
`'sourcedir'`
(It doesn't work without single quotation marks)

On the terminal, I type

```sh
    dcm2niix -m y -f %d 'file_path'
```

to use convert the .dcm files to .nii files in the file_path directory.
I would like to create a script to convert some .dcm files in separate directories automatically.
Hence, I wrote something like:

```sh
    file_path=Desktop/test/
    dcm2niix -m y -f %d '$file_path'
```

Here, I tried to treat the file path as a variable. But it doesn't work. The last line of code gets error.
Also,

```sh
    dcm2niix -m y -f %d "'$file_path'"
```

and

```sh
    dcm2niix -m y -f %d '"$file_path"'
```

and

```sh
    dcm2niix -m y -f %d `'$file_path'`
```

doesn't work as well.

Errors I got from previous showed code:

> Output folder invalid: Desktop/test
>
> Output folder invalid: 'Desktop/test'
>
> Output folder invalid: "Desktop/test"
>
> Output folder invalid: $file_path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `''` around your file_path in terminal only in case you have special characters like spaces or globs inside it. Which is not the case for `Desktop/test/`. But in your script, you have a variable `$file_path` which you want to expand into `Desktop/test/`, so the `''` prevent this. Try using double quotes `"` instead of `'`. Or try to escape the special meaning of the single quote marks using `\'` instead of `'`.

```sh
    dcm2niix -m y -f %d "$file_path"
```

or

```sh
    dcm2niix -m y -f %d \'"$file_path"\'
```

But I doubt that `<sourcedir>` really needs single quote marks.

Comment: `dcm2niix -m y -f %d "$file_path"`
works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Quoting in the shell has 2 main purposes:

1. prevent "word splitting" -- ensure that piece of text is received as one single argument by the command to which you're giving the quoted item.
2. prevent "globbing" -- ensure you're not accidentally treating the text as a glob pattern which may expand into a list of filenames.

Double quotes will allow things like variable expansion and command substitution to occur within.
Single quotes do not allow any expansions.

Quotes inside quotes have no special purpose: inside a double quoted string, single quotes are just plain characters, and vice versa.

Also note that once the shell is ready to actually invoke the command, the quotes will be removed. The `dcm2niix` command will receive the argument `Desktop/test/` not `"Desktop/test/"`